# Syntax error at Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|, while trying to run a script file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automation, vagrant, rocket.chat

While I am trying to run the following script as a shell script, I get an error saying

```
./install_local.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `"2"'
./install_local.sh: line 8: `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|'
```

What could be the reason for this? [Vagrant source](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/automation-tools/vagrant/)

```
        # -*- mode: ruby -*-
    # vi: set ft=ruby :

    # All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
    # configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
    # backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
    # you're doing.
    Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
      config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
      config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = "2048"
      end
      config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      SHELL
    end
```

Comment: the Vagrantfile is ok - please add the `install_local.sh` script

Comment: @FrédéricHenri This is the `install_local.sh` script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some confusion

Your script is a Vagrantfile not a shell script. Rename your `install_local.sh` as `Vagrantfile` and run `vagrant up`

Comment: I renamed `install_local.sh` to `Vagrantfile` and run `vagrant up`. It says `Path: /home/ubuntu/Vagrantfile
Line number: 138
Message: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`

Comment: The total number of lines however in the file are `125`

Comment: so this is not from the Vagrantfile - show the full error, its related to another script